# How to execute php codeigniter controller from batch file

Tags: php, batch-file, codeigniter-3

When I tried to run the script manually on the command line, working fine.The same code run in the batch file not working.
How to run the CodeIgniter controller in the batch file?

file name : crone-job.bat

```
cd D:\www\Apache2.4\htdocs\reech\

D:\php7.0\php.exe index.php crone/recordCountStatus >D:\www\Apache2.4\htdocs\reech\result.txt
```

Error: Could not open input file: index.php

Answer (score 2):

I dont think your case same like me, i hope this can be solve it, like my case :

- Windows 10
- PHP Version 5.6.23
- XAMPP v3.2.2

i have struture xampp installation like this
 - Drive E:\folder1\xampp\htdocs\currentworkspace (Root Codeigniter folder)

And i create bat file like this

```
@echo off
set "PATH=%PATH%;e:\folder1\xampp\htdocs\currentworkspace"
call e:
call cd folder1\xampp\htdocs\currentworkspace
:loop
call php index.php our_controller_name
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 3 -w 10000 >NUL
goto :loop
```

and save :)

" call e: " <<< because my default cmd always on drive C:

PING 1.1.1.1 -n "3" <<< 3 second

Sorry for bad english, but on my case it solve :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code,

Step 1: select the drive '**D**' or else

Step 2: select the **App location**

Step 3: php location  '**D:\php\php.exe**' or set in environment variables

Step 4: index.php  followed by controller_name/method_name ex: **index.php 
crone/recordCountStatus**

Step 5:save as **.bat** file and run this file in **Task Scheduler**

```
D:
cd www\Apache2.4\htdocs\reech\
set LOGFILE_DATE=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,3%-%DATE:~0,2%
set LOGFILE_TIME=%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%
set LOGFILE=%LOGFILE_DATE%-%LOGFILE_TIME%
D:\php\php.exe index.php crone/recordCountStatus  >>D:\www\Apache2.4\htdocs\reech\cron\log\dump-import-elasticsearch-log.txt
```